# Change Keybinding for Auto-Complete

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

Is there a way to make Emacs' `auto-complete` package not trigger menu completion on return key but instead on some other key-combination say C-Return? For a fast typist having it bound to return often causes non-deterministic behaviour of return. This because its behaviour now depends on how fast I type the previous characters.

See https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do exactly what you want

```
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "RET") nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map [return] nil)
(define-key ac-completing-map [(control return)] 'ac-complete)
```

I didn't try it on the terminal as I'm on windows at the moment.